# Collapsing some AST subtrees in Antlr using rewrite rules

Tags: tree, url-rewriting, antlr

I have the following grammar (i'm showing only the important sectons)

```
packageDeclaration
    :   PACKAGE qualifiedIdentifier SEMI -> ^(PACKAGE qualifiedIdentifier+) 
    ;

qualifiedIdentifier
    :   (   IDENT               ->  IDENT
        )
        (   DOT ident=IDENT     ->  ^(DOT $qualifiedIdentifier $ident)
        )*
    ;
```

and let's say i have a package decleration of "package a.b.c" (Java parser btw)

What i get now is something of the form
(package (. (. a b) c))

what i want is to inline the package so that i get
(package a.b.c)

I would prefer not to change the rewriting for the qualifiedIdentifier, but only for the packageDeclaration.

How can i do this.

I understand what you mean by alias and + now.  But i'm still unclear about the difference between qualifiedIdentifier and $qualifiedIdentifier in the rewrite rule.

As for my second question, what i mean is that i removed the rewrite rule for qualifiedIdentifier and for the package i have the following:

```
packageDeclaration
    :   PACKAGE ident=qualifiedIdentifier SEMI -> ^(PACKAGE $ident+) 
    ;
```

What i get as a result of this is nested tokens as in:

```
 (package
    (a) [end:a]

    (.) [end:.]

    (b) [end:b]

    (.) [end:.]

    (c) [end:c]
  ) [end:package]

Each token is represented as "(<token's text property>) [end: <token's text property>]"
```

I hope it's clear in the output above but i have one parent token (package) with 5 children.  Now they are in the correct order and all that.  What i would like is the same parent with only one child as in:

```
 (package
    (a.b.c) [end:a.b.c]
  ) [end:package]
```

Comment: A well phrased, detailed question with enough of the grammar posted to be answered. Well done!

Comment: lol thanks, it's easier now that i understand more of antlr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the `DOT`'s from the tree and only keep the tokens `a`, `b` and `c` from `import a.b.c;` (with `PACKAGE` as root, of course) try:

```
qualifiedIdentifier
  :  IDENT (DOT IDENT)* -> IDENT+
  ;
```

or with the `DOT`'s, simply remove the rewrite rule:

```
qualifiedIdentifier
  :  IDENT (DOT IDENT)*
  ;
```

By the way, your `packageDeclaration` has an error in it:

```
packageDeclaration
  :  PACKAGE qualifiedIdentifier SEMI -> ^(PACKAGE qualifiedIdentifier+)
  ;
```

`qualifiedIdentifier+` should be `qualifiedIdentifier` instead.

> *Coder wrote:*
>
> I would prefer not to change the rewriting for the qualifiedIdentifier, but only for the packageDeclaration.

That is not possible.

Unless you do not use `qualifiedIdentifier` inside `packageDeclaration`, in which case you could do something like:

```
packageDeclaration
  :  PACKAGE IDENT (DOT IDENT)* SEMI -> ^(PACKAGE IDENT+)
  ;
```

---

### EDIT

Regarding your comments:

> *Coder wrote:*
>
> I'm a little confused about the meaning of + in the rewrite rule. The documentation here antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Tree+construction says that you can break apart trees into sequences "a : (^(ID INT))+ -> INT+ ID+ ; // break apart trees into sequences ".

From the rule:

```
a 
  :  (^(ID INT))+ -> INT+ ID+
  ;
```

`(^(ID INT))+` means there are one or more `ID`'s and one ore more `INT`'s, and only then you can use `+` in the rewrite rule (everything to the right of ->).

You on the other hand have:

```
packageDeclaration 
  :  PACKAGE qualifiedIdentifier SEMI
  ;
```

there's only one `qualifiedIdentifier` in there, so you can only use that sinle `qualifiedIdentifier` in your rewrite rule (no `+`!)

> *Coder wrote:*
>
> I'm also confused about the difference between specifying an alias in the rewrite rule as in "PACKAGE ident:qualifiedIdentifier -> $ident" vs, using quanlifiedIdentifier vs $quanlifiedIdentifier

An alias can be used if it's not apparent which not apparent which rule should be placed where in the tree or if you want more control over how the children are placed. For example, given the rule:

```
name
  :  ID '.' ID
  ;
```

and you want the first `ID` to become the right child. Doing:

```
name
  :  ID '.' ID > ^(NAME ID ID)
  ;
```

will place the first ID as the left child. To make it the right child, do:

```
name
  :  a=ID '.' b=ID > ^(NAME $b $a)
  ;
```

---

### EDIT II

> Coder wrote:
>
> What i get as a result of this is nested tokens as in:
>
> ***(SNIP)***
>
> Each token is represented as ...

Okay, I see what you mean. You must understand that the parser "feeds of" the lexer. The lexer chops up the input of characters and creates tokens from these characters (`IDENT` is such a token, just as `DOT` is). These tokens are then passed to the parser. The parser can't just create or merge tokens. So the answer is: what you want is not easily done, it certainly is not possible to do in "ANTLR syntax" inside your grammar.

Comment: cool, i will try that thanks.  I'm a little confused about the meaning of + in the rewrite rule. The documentation here http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Tree+construction says that you can break apart trees into sequences "a : (^(ID INT))+ -> INT+ ID+ ; // break apart trees into sequences
".  I'm also confused about the difference between specifying an alias in the rewrite rule as in "PACKAGE ident:qualifiedIdentifier -> $ident" vs, using quanlifiedIdentifier vs $quanlifiedIdentifier

Comment: I tried what you suggested to remove the rewrite rule as in 'qualifiedIdentifier
  :  IDENT (DOT IDENT)*
  ;
' but i now get one token for each package and DOT.  what i would like is two tokens as in (package a.b.c).  Is that possible?

Comment: Ok that's fine, i can parse it out in Java as i need it, i just wanted to make sure there is no easy way to do it in ANTLR before i roll my own tree  library wrapper lol.  Also perhaps i missed you answer to "I understand what you mean by alias and + now. But i'm still unclear about the difference between qualifiedIdentifier and $qualifiedIdentifier in the rewrite rule.".  Did you answer this somewhere and i missed it?

Comment: @Coder, the `$qualifiedIdentifier` used in the rule itself (`qualifiedIdentifier`) causes the tree to be recursively filled with child nodes: it's a bit hard to explain...

Comment: I'm assuming you mean $qualifiedidentifier in the rewrite and qualifiedIdentifier in the rule.  I did more testing with this and i don't think you can specify qualifiedIdentifier in the rewrite. In which case it makes sense.  My confusion was only in the rewrite.  Thanks again for all the help.  I'm glad this works for me.  It's very powerful and i'm glad i didn't have to roll my own (I considered it lol)

Comment: @Code, yes, correct: you need the `$` in front of `qualifiedidentifier` in that rewrite rule. You're welcome.